# In a width of 1600 chrome is picking up a mediaquery of 1455px

Tags: css, drupal

I have been searching for hours....
My css is behaving different on my localhost then on my hosted environment.

In my hosted environment for some reason only chrome, in a width of 1600 is picking a @media query of 1455px.
However the same css behaves properly on my localhost.

I have flushed browsers cache as well as my drupal's cache however no result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Drupal - or your web server - isn't concatenating multiple CSS files in such a way that your stylesheet rules are being overwritten. Use the developer tools in your browser to inspect the element in question and see what CSS is being applied and in what order.

Comment: Theme folder and css file are 100% identical. I inspected the element: chrome gives my css data however the part from mediascreen 1450 while chrome is reading my localhost element with the correct screen